# Where is $f(z) = |x^2 - y^2| + 2i|xy|$holomorphic?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I want to find the region where the function $f(z) = |x^2 - y^2| + 2i|xy|$ for $x = Re(z)$, $y = Im(z)$, is holomorphic.

Clearly $f$ is not differentiable at the five points that cause $| ... |$ to be $0$. However, I am not clear on where to go from here. The $CR$-equations yield messy equations and don't see useful at the moment.

I think that $f$ is holomorphic on $\{z \mid (Re(z) >0 \; \wedge \; Im(z)>0) \text{ or }  (Re(z) <0 \; \wedge \; Im(z)<0)\}$. Anyone else agree?

Comment: You can get rid of the absolute value if you study the function on each of the eight regions separated by $x=0; y=0; y=x; y=-x$. If you also use $f(-z)=f(z)$ and $f(\bar z)=f(z)$ then you'll only have to do it on two of the eight regions.

Comment: About your edit, Note that for the region $\Im(z)>\Re(z)>0:\ f(z)=-\bar z^2$, so it's not holomorphic on that part.

Comment: Note that $f'(0) = 0$ from a simple size estimate. (What five points are you talking about?)

Comment: @zhw. $(0,0),(1,1),(-1,-1),(-1,1),(1,-1)$

Comment: And @Farnight I don't quite understand your hint. Do you mind posting as Answer to give a more detailed response?

Comment: What about $(2,2)$ and any other point on the lines $|y|=|x|?$ And when you write $|...|$ you could also mean $xy=0.$

Comment: So $f$ is not complex differentiable for any $|y|=|x|$ and for any $x,y$ s.t. $xy =0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ is differentiable whenever $x^2-y^2\neq 0;\ x\neq0 $ and $y\neq 0$.

It's easy to show that $f(-z)=f(z)$ and $f(\bar z)=f(z)$

---

Consider $z\in \Bbb C \text{ s.t }  x^2-y^2>0 \text{ and } xy>0$

[image: x^2-y^2>0 and xy>0]

$f(z)=z^2$ : holomorphic.

---

Now for $z\in \Bbb C \text{ s.t }  x^2-y^2<0 \text{ and } xy<0$

[image: x^2-y^2<0 and xy<0]

$f(z)=-z^2$ : holomorphic

---

For $z\in\Bbb C \text{ s.t }  x^2-y^2>0 \text{ and } xy<0$

[image: x^2-y^2>0 and xy<0]

$f(z)=\bar z^2$ : NOT holomorphic

---

And finally for $z\in \Bbb C \text{ s.t }  x^2-y^2<0 \text{ and } xy>0$

[image: x^2-y^2<0 and xy>0]

$f(z)=-\bar z^2$ : NOT holomorphic.

Comment: Very nice reply! How did you make those graphs? Also, this all implies that $f$ is holomorphic ONLY when both $x^2 - y^2 <0$ and $xy < 0$ or when both $x^2 - y^2 > 0$ and $xy > 0$. Correct? You showed that if one or the other was less than or greater than $0$ then the resulting function would not be holomorphic.

Comment: I didn't make the graphs. I used Wolfram Alpha. Here's an [example](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x^2-y^2%3C0+and+xy%3E0)

Comment: Hm, I wonder how I can do that with TiKZ. Thank you for the answer.